# Invariance principle, definition of order and informal order

Tags: algorithm

I know and fully understand the concept of principle. I explain it briefly.

**Invariance principle**

Two programs of the same algorithm only differ by a constant factor. (In temporal efficiency).

[image]

**Definition of order**

Let two functions [image] and [image] be said that [image] belongs to the order of [image] if there is a constant c and a threshold [image]:

[image]

**Informal order**

But I do not understand well where the formula of the definition of informal order is born, whose formula is:

[image]

Why are there two constants c1 and c2? Shouldn't it be a single constant c?

Comment: I've never heard of "informal order", but this looks like to be combining t1=O(t2) and t2=O(t1) with the assumption that t1, t2 > 0 (and missing the part about there being an n0 and that the inequalities hold for n>=n0).

Comment: The naming of the terminology is very non-standard throughout, "invariance principle", "temporal efficiency", "same algorithm"; it's all very unusual.